# angular keeping objects synced through app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reference

*This is an angular question as well as a javascript question.*

I have a lot of objects in our angular app coming from a backend that need to stay up to date. I am having trouble setting up good databindings to sync this through my app.

I created a DataService service that connects via websocket to our backend. Fetches data as required and caches it locally in an object called `store`. For example:

When a controller needs a list of users it will query the DataService like so:

```
DataService.get(users, {}).then(
  /* function to set something on the scope */
)
// (or as a resolve)
```

The DataService will fetch the users from our backend and a) locally cache the users in a store object and b) return an array with the result.

When another controller needs the same data we just return the cache.

---

This works great, except when the data changes and the backend tells the DataService about it. The DataService can update its local store cache but the controller does not know about those changes. Example doom scenarios:

- When a controller needs the full list of users, and after some time a new user gets added (outside of the angular environment; via the backend), how can the DataService update the earlier returned array?
- Controllers can request a specific subset of users (for example all users from city A). When a new users from city A enters the system, how should the DataService know this was something the controller was interested a while backt? If the DataService stores all queries it needs a way of matching new users (for example) to these queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a big fan of the [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource) service in the Angular core. When you use this, the properties returned from your data are assigned to the object on the instance of the $resource object. So

```
// js
scope.myThing = $resource('thing_url').get();

// html
{{ myThing.myProperty }}
```

This works by taking advantage of Angular's digest cycles. When resource is returned, the template "magically" works. This is actually because the `$resource` service kicks off a digest cycle when it completes its request, and the bindings now display the correct information. You can do the same thing with watchers:

```
scope.$watch('myThing.myProperty', function (newValue) { /... });
```

You could do something similar: create a service that returns an object containing the results from your server. Assuming you can connect to an event on your web-socket layer, you can then kick off a digest cycle whenever the data has been updated. In this way, the controllers and templates will be update.

---

Question Author addition:

Kicking of digest cycles in the service is only half of the work. The other half is making sure you don't overwrite the references to objects (a single model) and arrays (a collection of models). You can achieve this [by using `angular.copy` when updating the local models inside your service](http://tech.pro/blog/2131/keeping-angular-service-list-data-in-sync-among-multiple-controllers).

pseudo code of our working solution:

- Create a store object inside an API service (serves as a cache of all database data)
- Whenever a controller needs certain information it queries the API service.
- The API service requests that data from the backend and stores it locally in the store object.
- Besides the store object we also created a minimal query parser able to filter the store object in the same way the backend filters (we have a mongo style query API where queries are objects like `{city: "amsterdam"}` or `{city: {"!": "amsterdam"}}`).
- Run the query against the local store, save the query and the results and pass it back the requester (a directive or controller).
- Whenever a model updates, rerun all queries that might be associated. If the results change, use `copy.angular` to change the object / array without loosing the reference. After that kick off the digest cycle so the controllers are aware of changes in the data.

This solves all doomscenarios:

> When a controller needs the full list of users, and after some time a new user gets added (outside of the angular environment; via the backend), how can the DataService update the earlier returned array?

`angular.copy`

> Controllers can request a specific subset of users (for example all users from city A). When a new users from city A enters the system, how should the DataService know this was something the controller was interested a while backt? If the DataService stores all queries it needs a way of matching new users (for example) to these queries.

The service will automatically rerun all queries whenever the underlying data changes. This way the service will keep all data throughout whole of angularland up to date.

Comment: Thanks, will definitely try this. But this still means in that service I need to store specific requests (like doom scenario 2: users from city A) and a way that when the models change (new user from city A) the service can determine whether this user should be included or not. Right?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it. Both require you to inject `$rootScope` into your service.

First way is good if you are using something like `$scope.users = DataService.users` in your controllers. Just trigger all scopes to update on incoming message, e.g.:

```
$rootScope.$apply(function () {
    users.push(newUser);
});
```

The second way is to broadcast an event from root scope when message from server is received:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('server:update', data);
```

And listen to it in your controllers:

```
$scope.$on('server:update', function (data) {
    // Whatever you need to do
});
```

Comment: The problem is that our application has a lot of different controllers, at this moment around 30 but this will increase (also around 15 directives, some which load data dynamically). The first would require to bloat the rootScope with properties for everything we need to load dynamically? I'm gonna try the second one: when something changes each controller can figure out whether it's something he's interested in. This means a lot of boilerplate code in every controller..